# It is/was the best goal I have ever seen

Tags: word-choice, tense-agreement

I have a question related to grammar. I saw a memorable goal in 2015. I told my friend "It was the best goal I had ever seen"? In this case, I wanted to say that the goal was my favourite goal till then.

Now, If I want to say the goal is still my favourite goal, ***'is' or 'was'*** : What form should I use in the sentence "It is/was the best goal I have ever seen" ?

I have seen in my grammar book that tenses should match and therefore I think it may be right to write “It is the best goal I have ever seen”. But I am not sure. Can you please make it clear?

Comment: "It (still) is the best goal I have ever seen" is good.

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by *seeing a goal*? I don't get it.

Comment: @user3169, I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) the OP is refering to a goal in a particular sport that was particularly well executed. So 'seeing a goal' would refer to witnessing a very well executed score in sports.

Comment: @Imperator Would you classify them as good/better/best?

Comment: @user3169 If the goal was well executed, with no comparison, it is good, if it is objectively or subjectively better executed than another goal, it is better, and if it is objectively or subjectively better than any goal, it is the best.

Comment: @Imperator Sure, but is this what people really say? It seems unnatural, but then I'm a baseball fan, not football/soccer.

Comment: @user3169 It's highly regional, but yes, 'nice goal' is common, with a common response being 'so-and-so scored a better one', with a followup of 'yeah, but the best goal was scored by whatshisface last game'.